# no master manifest attribute, in TagesdienstC.jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I created an jar Data and now the cmd calls me this : no master manifest attribute, in TagesdienstC.jar. But my MANIFEST Data have all Informations which are needed.

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.einsundeins.tagesdienst.Main

and if I unzip my jar data in the MANIFEST Data aren't this but this:Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Built-By: glorioso
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_112-google-v7

Can anyone pls help me

Greetings